# Does BS4 offer a means to size `.input-group` down on various devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to size a BS4 input-group down as and when it is loaded on various devices. Kinda like how you can tell a col what it should be displaying on various screens. I.e.

`<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>`

> I want to do something similar on mobile devices, I.e. on a desktop
>   use `.input-group-lg` on a mobile use `.input-group-sm` etc.
>
> Is this something BS4 can do? (I can't see any mention of it in the
>   docs?)

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/tkmujo9q/20/) with an example, if it helps.

Comment: You can edit the src sass files to create your own, or use media queries to override default behavior.

Comment: So BS4 can't handle this natively?

Comment: I don't believe so, not at this time: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#sizing

Comment: We'll that's a little frustrating... Ok I'll sort it myself. Thanks for the info!  +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created two custom class for `input-group` resizing for `small, medium` and `large` screen.
`1st` for *small+medium* screen like **.input-group-sm-md** class.
`2nd` for *small+medium+large* screen like **.input-group-sm-md-lg** class.
I follow `breakpoint` of Bootstrap4.
Doc Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

**`Note:`** check on `Full page` from snippet box and resize browser to check input-group `resize reflection`.

I hope below snippet will help you.

```css
@media(min-width: 991px){
  /*Class for small + medium &large screen*/
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.custom-select,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.form-control:not(textarea) {
    height: calc(1.5em + 1rem + 2px);
  }
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.custom-select,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.form-control,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.input-group-append>.btn,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.input-group-append>.input-group-text,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.input-group-prepend>.btn,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.input-group-prepend>.input-group-text {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 575px){
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.custom-select,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.form-control:not(textarea),
  .input-group-sm-md>.custom-select,
  .input-group-sm-md>.form-control:not(textarea){
    height: calc(1.5em + .5rem + 2px);
  }
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.custom-select,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.form-control,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.input-group-append>.btn,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.input-group-append>.input-group-text,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.input-group-prepend>.btn,
  .input-group-sm-md-lg>.input-group-prepend>.input-group-text,
  /*Class small+medium screen*/
  .input-group-sm-md>.custom-select,
  .input-group-sm-md>.form-control,
  .input-group-sm-md>.input-group-append>.btn,
  .input-group-sm-md>.input-group-append>.input-group-text,
  .input-group-sm-md>.input-group-prepend>.btn,
  .input-group-sm-md>.input-group-prepend>.input-group-text{
    padding: .25rem .5rem;
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <form action="https://stackoverflow.com/users/7052927/raeesh-alam?tab=profile">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm-md">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="input-group-sm-md">
          <span class="input-group-append">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm-md-lg">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="input-group-sm-md-lg">
          <span class="input-group-append">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for the effort! I've already implemented my own solution though I'll mark this a correct for anyone that might come along after the fact. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```